# MSBuild and Skipping target "<TargetName>" because it has no outputs

Tags: msbuild

I've been doing a little dabbling with MSBuild before, but this is my first forray into partial builds. I've got everything to work, but not as well as I'd like. I cannot get around this message:

`Skipping target "BuildLocalizerSetting" because it has no outputs.
Though the target has declared its outputs, the output specification only references empty properties and/or empty item lists.`

If I delete the `Inputs` attribute from the target everything works fine. I suspect this has to do with missing transforms, but specifying a transform is not really possible.

My setup is slightly different from a typical build scenario. I have a manifest file, which contains a list of files which should be compiled. I.e. I go from a scenario where one input file generates a - potentially long - list of items in an item group.

I've build a custom task for parsing the manifest file, and it seems to do the task well. Although I did run into one snag, The `TaskItem` doesn't allow setting of certain wellknown metadata, like: "Filename", "Extension", "ModifiedTime", etc. The issue was quickly resolved by implementing `ITaskItem` in a custom `TaskItem` class. I know dirty checking works as it should, since MSBuild does detect that those items has beeen modified. But now I wonder... **Do I risk having a build error on some odd platform due to that implementation?**

But most importantly, **Why can't MSBuild accept that the inputs have changed, and then conclude that the outputs have changed as well?**

Every example I've found assumes either a one to one relationship between input and output, or a many to one, but in my scenario I go from one to many, can that be done?

Comment: Are you not setting `Outputs` on the `Target`? You could try using `<Error Text="@(ExpressionYouPutInOutputs)"/>` somewhere to see if it is empty or not. You should put your many in `Outputs` and MSBuild will detect that as any of the outputs being older than the one input manifest file as requiring a rebuild. Or you could put both the manifest file and all inputs in the `Inputs` and all the outputs in `Outputs` and any file in `Outputs` older than the manifest or any input will cause a rebuild.